# Создать список, который содержит последовательное количество повторений элемента

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть следующая последовательность:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'index':range(13),'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,3,3,4,3,5]})

index   a
0       1
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       2
5       2
6       1
7       1
8       3
9       3
10      4
11      3
12      5
```

Необходимо подсчитать количество повторений каждого элемента и добавить столбец, например `Range`:

```
index   a   Range
0       1   1
1       1   2
2       1   3
3       2   1
4       2   2
5       2   3
6       1   1
7       1   2
8       3   1
9       3   2
10      4   1
11      3   1
12      5   1
```

Хочется сделать это без циклов, а то у меня слишком много вычислений и в итоге получается очень долгое выполнение.

Мой код:

```
group = a.groupby(["a"])[["index"]]
a = a.assign(Range = a[['index']]-group.transform(min)+1)
```

Но при попадании одинаковых значений, например, в столбце `a` идут три единицы подряд, а потом они повторяются в id: 6,7, он считает с того места, где прошлые единицы закончились, т.е. это будет 7,8 единицы в списке:

```
index   a   Range
0       1   1
1       1   2
2       1   3
3       2   1
4       2   2
5       2   3
6       1   7
7       1   8
8       3   1
9       3   2
10      4   1
11      3   4
12      5   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [117]: a['Range'] = a.groupby((a.a != a.a.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1

In [118]: a
Out[118]:
    index  a  Range
0       0  1      1
1       1  1      2
2       2  1      3
3       3  2      1
4       4  2      2
5       5  2      3
6       6  1      1
7       7  1      2
8       8  3      1
9       9  3      2
10     10  4      1
11     11  3      1
12     12  5      1
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо!